# Why is my variable of type Boolean getting reset in a keydown event?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

### Problem

In the following code,

- The *first log* prints **false**
- The *second log* prints **the key that was pressed**

```js
const KEY_S_LOWER = 83; // So others don't have to figure it out.

var triggered = false;
console.log(triggered);

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if ((event.keyCode === KEY_S_LOWER) && (triggered === false)) {
    console.log(triggered);
    triggered = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
```

### Questions

- How did the type for `triggered` get reset?
- Is it possible to access global state in an arrow function?

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo. I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: I assigned `83` to a variable called `KEY_S_LOWER` to assist others in debugging...

Comment: In my case second log prints false when I press the 's' key

Comment: I'm using the Firefox console in Developer Tools (Firefox Developer Edition). Could this make any difference?

Comment: @iluvfugu I doubt it, the `triggered` variable is only assigned boolean values, so it should only print `true`, `false`, or `undefined`, but never the key the was pressed.

Comment: `triggered` is not otherwise in use in global scope, afaik. Therefore, as long as there is no `triggered =` (or equivalent destructuring syntax) with an operand that isn't just `true` or `false` (or another `console.log`), this should be impossible. If you get the behavior you describe, you are likely not showing the code responsible for the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I copied this code verbatim and the issue was still occurring.  But after hard-reloading the page, I can no longer reproduce the issue.